# Is JavaScript forEach slower than for loops even in Mozilla Rhino?

Tags: javascript, java, for-loop, foreach, rhino

I use Servoy Developer at work, and it uses Mozilla Rhino which is a JavaScript engine written in Java. Will how forEach is implemented into Java make a difference in if I should use for loops over forEach?

I’ve read that JavaScript forEach is slower than just using a for loop, since it makes a function call for each element.

Comment: If it really matters, why not go measure it for the use case you care about?

Comment: _"I’ve read that JavaScript forEach is slower than just using a for loop"_ There is no singular "JavaScript". There are at least a few dozen JavaScript engines, runtimes, interpreters. JavaScript has been implemented using JavaScript https://github.com/engine262/engine262. Each is free to implement ECMA-262 however they see fit; "implementation details". Now whether than implementation is conformant with ECMA-262 or not is a different question.

Comment: There's plenty of factors that can make loop X slower than equivalent loop Y. The range would include anything from hardware and software defects to compiler optimizations on the byte code or machine code. `Array.forEach` and similar are really more about readability and ease of understanding, they're not trying to outrun a basic for loop with equal functionality. The speed difference between classic `for` and the modern "loop with callback" of `forEach` and friends is effectively negligible compared to what the loop is doing on each iteration.